# how to create credentials for purview account using net SDK?

Tags: azure-sdk-.net, azure-purview

I only search this [SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/Azure.Analytics.Purview.Catalog_1.0.0-beta.1/sdk/purview) about purview account ,not sure which method I can invoke to create credentials

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, there is no SDK available to create credentials for purview account using .Net SDK.

Currently, it's possible to create via Azure Portal.

I will let you know once it available.